# Can I use Route53 nameservers in addition to my hostgator nameservers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, nameservers

My domain(say abc-xyz.com) is registered with hostgator. For DNS as well, I am using hostgator and there are 4 nameserver entries listed.

However, now I wish to add route 53 as my DNS service so that I will be able to craete sub1.abc-xyz.com and sub2.abc-zyz.com. 
I created a Hosted zone for abc-xyz.com in Route 53 console and it shows 4 name servers which I suppose I need to copy on my hostgator.
When I copied the 4 entries to hostgator  along-with the existing nameserver entries (which means total 8 nameserver entries), my DNS entries stopped working. All DNS resolutions started failing.

Is there a way, for me to use both hostgator and Route53 simultaneously as my DNS service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Route53 as your authorised NS than you need to remove the Hostgator DNS server entries.
However you can use both the Route53 and Hostgator name servers, but I would not recommend it, until and unless you have a very strong use case.

Just make sure in your Route53 zone file you make all record entries which were in hostgator zone.